# VS2019: NPM reference to typescript always shows "not installed" for particular versions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm using VS2019 16.4. I've got an ASP.NET Core web app which references TypeScript via its packages.json file. If I reference TypeScript v. 3.6.2, the Dependencies/npm tree shows no problems. But when I list a different version, say 3.7.3, even though it installs correctly, I see:

[image]

To be clear, there's no actual problem other than this yellow caution mark. My webpack builds work fine. But I'd like to understand what might be going on here. Has anyone else seen this? Does VS use additional logic in particular around the Typescript NPM package in this context?

Update: This reprocudes out of the box with the ASP.NET Core React / Redux template. Just:

- create a new project
- Move "packages.json" from the "clientapp" subdirectory into the parent directory (the root of the web application project). Only when packages.json is in the root will we see the visualization of the npm packages in the GUI. It's interesting that they made the template such that this won't work as expected in the GUI)
- Typescript starts out at 3.6.4, and shows correctly. Update it in packages.json to 3.7.3, and you'll soon see "typescript - not installed"

Update: This appears fixed in newer versions of VS2019 (later than 16.4)

Comment: I have no problem.Have you tried to rebuild the solution,close the solution and re-open it?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. Can you confirm the version of typescript you're pulling via package.json, and the version of VS you're using?

Comment: Yes,I have checked that.Do you have the problem in a new mvc project?

Comment: I've updated the post. Yes, I can reproduce this out of the box with the react/redux asp.net core template, both on 16.4, and 16.4.1